# replacing numbers in order

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like the below:

```
id  cluster_num  date
a        1        07/31/2000  
b        3        07/31/2000    
b        3        07/31/2000    
c        5        07/31/2000   
d        1        08/31/2000    
e        2        08/31/2000    
e        4        08/31/2000   
f        4        08/31/2000
```

I would like to replace each `cluster_num` for each date to be in numerical order
so for example the first date  07/31/2000 I would like the number to be replaced to be 1,2,3 rather than 1,3,5

```
id  cluster_num  date   
a        1        07/31/2000    
b        2        07/31/2000   
b        2        07/31/2000    
c        3        07/31/2000   
d        1        08/31/2000    
e        2        08/31/2000    
e        3        08/31/2000    
f        3        08/31/2000
```

I am not sure how to do this and any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Why is cluster_num for id = "e" different for date = "08/31/2000"?

Comment: @AnandaMahto -- I just fixed it for the OP.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, I was tempted to make the fix, but the mistake appears to be there in the original sample data too, so I hesitated.

Comment: @Ananda -- OK, rolled back, b/c it's probably better to take the OP at their word. Looks like the `id` column is completely uninvolved in this problem.

Comment: Please look at the two penultimate lines of the expected output.  Are those correct?

Comment: yes the id is not important in this problem its really the cluster num and date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach. Based on `match`.

```
transform(dat, cluster_num = ave(cluster_num, date, 
                                 FUN = function(x) match(x, unique(x))))

  id cluster_num       date
1  a           1 07/31/2000
2  b           2 07/31/2000
3  b           2 07/31/2000
4  c           3 07/31/2000
5  d           1 08/31/2000
6  e           2 08/31/2000
7  e           3 08/31/2000
8  f           3 08/31/2000
```

Comment: I like this one too. +1

Comment: Yes, this is a great idea. Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

*edited as per Josh's catch of my error*

This is a one liner if using `data.table`

```
## Convert your data. I am assuming original is called 'DF' 
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)


DT[,cluster_num:=as.integer(as.factor(id)),by=date]
```

Comment: Close, but won't this a produce `cluster_num` column that begins "1,2,3,4,...", rather  than "1,2,2,3,..." (which is what was requested)?  This should work: `DT[,cluster_num:=as.integer(as.factor(cluster_num)),by=date]` (though I'm sure there's a more elegant way than using `as.integer(as.factor())`).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, you are correct, thanks for catching that.  I edited the answer.  I think you may have meant `as.factor(id)`, no?

Comment: Possibly. It actually looks like the OP might want the new numbers based on the values  in `cluster_num`, rather than those in `id`. Also, on further reflection `as.integer(factor(id, levels=unique(id)))` is better. My first suggestion would give wrong results for id's that aren't in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try a combination of `by` and `rle` if your data are ordered:

```
x <- by(mydf$id, mydf$date, FUN=function(x) {
  a <- rle(as.character(x))$lengths
  rep(seq_along(a), a)
})
unlist(x, use.names=FALSE)
# [1] 1 2 2 3 1 2 2 3
```

Assign that output as your new "cluster_num" variable.

---

Borrowing the "factor" approach used by Ricardo and Josh and implementing it in base R, you could also use `ave`:

```
ave(as.character(mydf$id), mydf$date, FUN = function(x) as.integer(as.factor(x)))
```

Unlike the `rle` approach, the data do not need to be sorted first to generate the sequence.

---

If the sequence needs to be generated based on the current "cluster_num" change all references to "`mydf$id`" to "`mydf$cluster_num`" in the examples above.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

Before you start, you may want to make sure that the `date` column is formatted as date, otherwise the ordering might fail (check if `class(d$date)` returns `Date`, not `factor`).

```
library(plyr)
library(likert)

d$date <- as.Date(d$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
d1 <- arrange(d, date, cluster_num)
ddply(d1, .(date), function(x) {
  v <- x$cluster_num
  x$cluster_num <- recode(v, unique(v), seq_along(unique(v)))
  x
})


  id cluster_num       date
1  a           1 2000-07-31
2  b           2 2000-07-31
3  b           2 2000-07-31
4  c           3 2000-07-31
5  d           1 2000-08-31
6  e           2 2000-08-31
7  e           3 2000-08-31
8  f           3 2000-08-31
```

Comment: This doesn't do what the OP asked for. (Compare the first few values of your outputted `cluster_num` to those posted by the OP to see that.)